Why does my NASM code print a large value when printing a db byte variable as an int?
I'm coding in NASM, and I don't get what is going on. The Linux distro is an Ubuntu 16 64-bit, but the NASM is operating in 32-bit.
Expected output --> "Number is: 2"
Actual output --> "Number is: 134520868"
Code:
%include "io.inc"

section .data
    n1 db 2 ; I know it's a bad practice to define a db variable, it's just for a test
    msg: db 'number is: %d',10,0

section .text
extern printf
global main

main:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    push dword n1
    push msg
    call printf

    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret

I've tried to define n1 with dd, or pushing the content of n1, even with a register like eax.
Update: even when I do push dword [n1] the only thing that changes is that now the output is "Number is: 1836404226".
Update: you make me realize that I mis-typed "Number" in the code, sorry for that.

Your program doesn't match the final output: the text starts with "Number" rather than "number" like your msg format string, and 1836404226 is 0x6d754e02 (with 'N') not 0x6d756e02 (with 'n').  I guess you changed the format string as well.

You want a 32-bit number, so use dd and you don't want to print the address of the variable, but its contents. So:
n1 dd 2 ; ...

and
push dword [n1]
push msg
call printf


Or you could just do a zero-extending or sign-extending load.  It's not bad practice to have a uint8_t or int8_t global variable like the OP suggested, at least it's no worse than a uint32_t global variable.  movzx eax, byte [n1] / push eax.  Or just ask printf to ignore upper bytes with a %hhd or %hhu conversion, then you can just push dword [n1] even if it's only a db, as long as there's definitely some garbage after it, not an unmapped page.  (Code that links libc will definitely have some BSS space which goes right after .data so that's not a problem.)


i know it's a bad practice to define a db variable,

It is not bad practice.

If you want a byte variable, then using db is the
absolute right thing to do.

If you do not want a byte variable, then using db is
still not bad practice; it is a mistake.



it's just for a test

It being a test does not somehow invert the laws of the universe and make wrong things right.
Your printf() printed some nonsense number because you were not printing the contents of the variable: by using push n1 you were printing the address of the variable. (And addresses tend to be arbitrary large numbers.) The number 134520868 is 0x0804A024 in hex, and this looks like an address.
When you did push dword [n1] you still got some nonsense number, because n1 has been defined with db, so it is a byte, and this byte is followed by other bytes, (the letters 'n', 'u', and 'm' in your case,) and when these four bytes are read together as a dword they form some other number which is different from 2. Specifically, the number 1836404226 that you got in this case is 0x6D754E02 in hex, and if you break this down to bytes you get 2, 'N', 'u', and 'm'.  (Which means that the string was "Number" instead of what you have shown in the question, which is "number".)
You have (at least) two options:

Declare your variable using dd, and use push dword [n1]. The rest of the code remains the same.

Alternatively, keep the variable defined with db, but use movsx eax, byte [n1] or movzx eax, byte [n1] followed by push eax to sign-extend or zero-extend that byte into a dword, and push it into the stack. The rest of the code remains the same.



Since you are using the x86 tag, you are targeting a 16-bit architecture, where an int is 16-bits long - what are you talking about?  [x86-16] is specifically 16-bit x86.  [x86] includes all modes, but by itself without other tags would normally imply 32-bit mode.  And the OP said they're running NASM in 32-bit mode on Linux, like nasm -f el32 so it's not a 16-bit architecture, and int is 32 bits.  Have you not worked with assembly outside of DOS and bootloaders?

depending on your assembler's syntax flavor. - The OP says they're using NASM.  Also, push [word ptr n1] isn't valid anywhere AFAIK.  In MASM the word ptr goes outside the [], which are optional when no register is involved.  So push word ptr [n1] in MASM is push word [n1] in NASM.  Neither of which are what you want for 32-bit x86 on Linux: push dword [n1], and either use "%hhd" in the format string to treat it as an 8-bit integer (ignoring the high garbage), or like you said use dd.

@PeterCordes uh, yeah, I do not know what I was talking about. I believe I fixed everything now.

"It being a test does not somehow invert the laws of the universe and make wrong things right." you're totally right about it, i was so stressed that i forgot to specify, what i was trying to do is print a non signed number of 8 bits long, i thought it was logical to do it with a 8 bit long number.
Anyways im sorry for the inconvenient the only assembler that i manage to make work is ARM, this is a hole new world for me so im just trying to do my best.

@leo: movzx eax, byte [n1] is the ARM equivalent of ldrb.  ARM passes the first few args in registers; most 32-bit x86 calling conventions (including i386 SysV) only use the stack so you need to zero-extend and copy to the stack.  push alone can only copy, not zero-extend a narrower source, which is why you need an extra instruction for a 1-byte variable in memory.

First of all, push n1 pushes the address.  push dword [n1] loads 4 bytes from memory and pushes them.
Basic use of immediates vs. square brackets in YASM/NASM x86 assembly

msg: db ... comes right after n1: db 2, so a 4-byte (dword) load gets 3 bytes of ASCII characters as the high bytes of the integer.  A %d format takes all 4 of those bytes as the int to print.
x86 is little-endian, so if you'd used %#x in your format string you'd see 0x6d756e02 - notice that the low byte is the 2 you loaded.  6e is 'n' in ASCII / UTF-8, etc.  You could also use GDB to look at stack memory before the call.  See the bottom of the x86 tag wiki for asm GDB tips.


I know it's a bad practice to define a db variable, it's just for a test

It's not bad practice to have a char, uint8_t, or int8_t global variable.  It's no worse than a uint32_t global.  Whatever size your data is, you need to use appropriate instructions for it.  This is assembly, there's no compiler to implicitly convert types for you.
In this case, you need to load just a byte if you don't want to pull in other garbage.
The things you can do include:
Zero- or Sign-extend a byte into a register and push that
movzx eax, byte [n1] / push eax will load just a byte from memory, zero-extending to 32 bits (the width of EAX).  movsx is the same but with sign-extension.
This is what a C compiler would do for printf("...", n1) with int8_t n1 = 2;
Load high garbage but tell printf to only look at the low byte
Since you know you have valid data after your byte in this case, you can't segfault from going off the end of a page into an unmapped one.
push dword [n1] and use %hhd in your format string to treat arg as int8_t, only looking at the low byte.  See the Glibc printf man page.
Loading garbage past the end of a variable isn't something you can express in C, except maybe with memcpy(&tmp_int, &n1, sizeof(tmp_var));.  A very clever compiler could potentially do this asm optimization if you used a %hhd format string so it knew the high 3 bytes of what it pushed didn't matter.  Your n1 happens to be 4-byte aligned (since it's at the start of your .data in this file), so a 4-byte load can't be split across cache lines, so there's no downside.
Note that standard calling conventions including i386 System V allow narrow args to contain high garbage; they don't have to be zero or sign extended to 32-bit. (Except maybe as an undocumented extension required by clang, at least that's the case for register args in x86-64 Sys V.)  And anyway, printf in C terms is taking an int and %hd / %hhd conversions truncate it, since it's variadic so the default argument promotions apply: narrow integer types promote to int.)
Reserve 4 bytes for your global
n1: dd 2 allows push dword [n1] to load 0x0000002 from memory, so a %d conversion to print the whole thing as an int will print just 2.
In C terms, this is static int n1 = 2; instead of static int8_t n1 = 2;
